# React - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: web3-react, thirdweb

I'm fairly new to react and I started playing around with some Web3 libraries just to get a better understanding. Upon installing the thirdWeb SDK per the instructions, I'm getting the following error when I run npm start. I'm using React 18.2.0.

```
./node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/react/dist/thirdweb-dev-react.browser.esm.js 353:37
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (353:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         var reader = new FileReader();
|         reader.onload = function (event) {
>           setJsonString(event.target?.result);
|           var obj = JSON.parse(event.target?.result);
|           setImportedAddress(obj.address);
```

I've tried looking it up online but all I get is to update WebPack, but I'm using the latest version of React, Node, and thirdWeb. Can someone explain to me what this actually means and provides steps on how to resolve?